# Cookies causing django crash when upgrading from 1.3 to 1.4

Tags: django

So I upgraded from django 1.3 to 1.4, everything went smoothly. However a few users just get an `Internal Server Error`, thrown by nginx, usually when the server has crashed.

Investigating this showed that it was problems with cookies. The error in the log was:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing authentication backend
  site.app.backends.EmailModelBackend: "No module named site.app.backends"
```

This is because during the upgrade I reorganized my project, and this particular backend is now at `app.backends` rather than `site.app.backends`. Clearly this information is hard-coded into the auth cookie, which is causing the problem.

Is there any way to sort this out short of emailing users and telling them to clear their cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the default [database-backed sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/?from=olddocs#using-database-backed-sessions), then the reference to the old backend is stored in the `django_session` table, and the user's cookie is just a reference to the row in the database. In that case, you could prevent the errors by deleting all the session data from your database.

Think carefully before you do this. You might not want to delete all your session data -- for example, it will log out all of your users.

Comment: Logging out all users would not be the end of the world. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can blame this on cookies. Please go over your code again with a fine-toothed comb and look for a call into `site.app.backends`.

If you have access to a call-stack from the crash it will tell you exactly where to look.

Comment: There are none, I have double checked. This only affects browsers which were logged into the site before, and clearing cookies fixes it.

Comment: Have you really checked everywhere? Redirects? URLs? Models? Custom middleware?

Comment: `grep -r site.app.backends .`. No results. The only place it's referenced is in `settings.py` anyway.